# Determine whether an ideal is principal or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $I=\{a+b\sqrt{-3}: a+b \text{ even}\}$ be an ideal in $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. I want to determine whether $I$ is a principal ideal or not.

I've been trying to work with the ideal $(2)$. I know that $(2)\subset I$, but $I$ is not in $(2)$ since $(2)$ does not contain elements of the form $(2a+1)+(2b+1)\sqrt{-3}$ even though $(2a+1)+(2b+1)=2a+2b+2$, which is even  and hence in $I$. 
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ $I$ contains $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-3}$, two non-associate elements of norm $4$. Are there elements of norm $2$ in $R$?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it: since there do not exist $a,b$ such that $a^2+3b^2=2$, we have that $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-3}$ are irreducible but non-associate elements of norm 4. Since $2=(1+\sqrt{-3})(-1-\sqrt{-3})$, and neither factor divides $2$, we have that $1+\sqrt{-3}$ is not prime. Thus, $I$ cannot be principal since primes and irreducibles are the same in PIDS.

Comment: $(1 + \sqrt{-3})(-1-\sqrt{-3}) = 2 - 2 \sqrt{-3}$ though. Think easier: if $I = (x)$ what would the norm of $x$ be?

Comment: ok, so $(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})=2^2=4$, and since two of the three different terms are irreducible, we don't have unique factorization and hence it cannot be a PID.    If $I=(x)$, the norm would be $x^2$?

Comment: You're correct that $R$ is not a PID. And I meant $I = (x)$ as in $x = a + b \sqrt{-3}$. The question was what the norm of $x$ could be. Hint: multiplying $x$ with something gives elements of norm $4$.

Comment: The norm of x would be $a^2+3b^2$. To get a norm 4, we would need to multiply $x$ by another element to get an element of the form $c+d\sqrt{-3}$, where $c=2$ or $-2$, or where $c,d=1$ or $-1$. But these are all irreducible elements, so either $x$ or what we are multiplying it with is a unit, which means $x$ must have norm 4.